# Adding View On Top Of Map View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, mkmapview

I am not able to add this view on to the map view to be displayed ... I am working with the map view and I want to add a view on top of it... Here is what I have tried :

[image]

Here is my output : 
[image]

As far as I can see, the map view is covering the icon view!
[image]

I tried this too but I got the same output! Please forgive me if this is a silly mistake, I am relatively new to using MapViews. Thanks a lot for your help and I really appreciate it!

[image]

I tried your suggestions too :

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you used view debugger and checked if view actually exists? Or its frame being reset to zero and not appearing at all? Because your first set up of adding view on top of map view should have worked

Comment: Let me check! Thanks

Comment: I have added the things showing up in the view debugger to my question

Comment: Try to call `view.bringSubviewToFront(yourCustomView)` in `viewDidAppeaer`

Comment: Not working, I have updated the question

Comment: @Tejas what you have in `viewWillAppear` is not same as what was suggested try this `view.bringSubviewToFront(iconView)` you are asking icon view to bring map view to front when map view isn't even added as child to iconView, that's messed up use what has been suggested by @mmika1000 `view.bringSubviewToFront(iconView)` also no need to do it in `viewWIllAppear` call it only once in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: To me it seems like you add **another** map in the code to the view. When you look at the view debugger you can see the hierarchy containing something pink, the VC's view, *some other views*, the map view from the storyboard, your icon view **and then on top of it yet another MapView**. I'm pretty sure you're adding another map in the code somewhere. Can you find out what all the views on top are?

Comment: Plus your constraints are not working / present as you can see in the view debugger, your underlying views do not fill the screen. Can you please share the entire code of your ViewController? As I mention that, please always share code using the code snippet function, **don't use screenshots**

Comment: @tejas: Could have been better if you had asked mmika1000 to post the answer :) as he is the one who suggested it anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `view.bringSubviewToFront(iconView)` in your `viewDidLoad` function.

Also make sure you have correct layouting / constraints for all your views.

Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for the help. I found out that

```
view.bringSubviewToFront(iconView)
```

worked properly and it turns out that the first time it was suggested, I had written it wrongly! I really appreciate your help! Thanks again!

Comment: Ah I can see the error from the screenshot... :) You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need code to place a view on top of a map view. Just drag the icon view under the map view in the document hierarchy.